# did I fry Raspi I2C pins?

Tags: gpio, python, pi-4, hardware, i2c

So I wanted to test a sensor I have on the pi, the sensor has on-board level switchers supports both 5V and 3.3V  with a 10k pull-up resistor for both SCL/SDA, Mistakenly I wired the Vin into the 5V pin instead of the 3.3V pin. I measured the voltage at the SDA/SCL pins and read 3.6V. the sensor consumes 2.6 mA at 3.3V and 3.0 mA at 3.6V. I ran  `i2cdetect -y 1`  and returned the following[image: i2cdetect -y 1]

which is the default address of the sensor.

an error occurs when I run the following script(python3)

```
import time
import board
import adafruit_sgp40

i2c = board.I2C()  # uses board.SCL and board.SDA
sgp = adafruit_sgp40.SGP40(i2c)


while True:

    # For compensated raw gas readings
    """
    compensated_raw_gas = sgp.measure_raw(
        temperature=temperature, relative_humidity=humidity
    )
    print("Raw Data:", compensated_raw_gas)
    """

    # For Compensated voc index readings
    voc_index = sgp.measure_index(
    temperature=temperature, relative_humidity=humidity)

    print("VOC Index:", voc_index)
    print("")
    time.sleep(1)
```

**ERROR**
[image]

connections were checked multiple times with a successful continuity test,I tested two sensors with the same error. both sensors are connected using STEMMA QT wires. Searched about the error and most sources say it is a physical connection issue however the sensor is detected.
any help is highly appreciated, Thanks in advance

```
   ‘ Traceback (most recent call last):’
‘File "/home/nada/Desktop/sensor.py", line 23, in <module>’

‘sgp = adafruit_sgp40.SGP40(i2c)’
‘File 
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/adafruit_sgp40/_init_py",line 123, in _init_ self.initialize ()’
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/adafruit_sgp40/__init_ _py", line 146, in initialize
self_test = self._read_word_from_command(de lay_ms=250)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/adafruit_sgp40/_init_-py',line 293, in _read_word_from_command 12c. readinto (replybuffer, end=-replylen)
File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/adafruit_bus_device/i2c_device.py",line 81, in readinto self.i2c.readfrom_into(self.device_address, buf, start=start, end=end)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/busiopy", line 193, in readfrom_into
return self..
_i2c.readfrom_into(address, buffer, stop=stop)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/generic_linux/i2c.py",line59,inreadfrom_into
readin = self._i2c_bus.read_bytes(address, end - start)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/Adafruit_PureI0/smbus.py",line 170, in read_ bytes return self ._device.read(number)
SError: [Errno 121] Remote I/0 error
```

[image]

Comment: Check that the code is using bus 1 (GPIO 2/3) rather than bus 0 (GPIO 0/1).  Some Python modules default to bus 0 and you need it to use bus 1.

Comment: Checked the library couldn’t find any information on the bus. 
I ran the code in cmd error happen when creating the object “sgp”nevertheless I declared bus 1 in the script. 
The sensor has I2C address of 0x59. import time
import board
import adafruit_sgp40
import smbus
i2c = board.I2C()  # uses board.SCL and board.SDA
bus=smbus.SMBus(1)
sgp = adafruit_sgp40.SGP40(i2c)

Comment: DO NOT post illegible pictures of text post TEXT

Comment: @Milliways, I got you. Post was edited, tried to format it using “code” function it didn’t work for some reason. It’s a [Errno 121] Remote I/0 error

Comment: @joan
One library they had set the bus to 1. Still didn’t work
The code containing library above i didn’t see any smbus arguments, I think they used Busio.

Comment: The fact that you get an address (i.e. `59`) in the output of your `i2cdetect -y 1` command suggests that the driver for your device (i.e. `sgp40`) is not loaded. You should see a `UU` in position 59 if the driver is loaded. Check your `/boot/config.txt` file for errors.

Comment: @Seamus The software is reading the device directly.  It does not need a driver.

Comment: Double check the I2C connections are complete and not loose (SDA/SCL/ground).  Clear photos may help.

Comment: Doubled check the wires I even tried another Raspi with a different sensor and yielded the same results. The sensor does require a driver for operation which is CircuitPython, I tried an entirely different driver where the bus was set to 1 as you said but same error occurred.  Main driver https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_SGP40

Comment: CircuitPython is NOT a driver. To quote Adafruit "CircuitPython is a beginner friendly, open source version of Python for tiny, inexpensive computers called microcontrollers". In fact it is a proprietary Adafruit program, AFAIK not used by anyone else. It DOES NOT run on CPU like Pi - it is designed for microcontrollers.  To use it on a Pi you NEED to install an adaption layer Blinka. I suggest you seek and alternate driver for SGP40.

Answer (score 0):

You are unlikely to have damaged the Pi.

The Pi has on board 1.8k pullup to 3.3V so effectively you put 3.55V on the pins which would not have caused the substrate diodes to conduct.

---

While you may not have damaged the GPIO continuing to use excessive voltage will compromise logic levels.

You should remove the extraneous pullups.